# Getting user input data using sys.stdin

Tags: python-3.x, stdin

```
import sys

data = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    data.append(line)
```

I did not use `.read()` or `.readline()`
but this code works reading the data. It read the data line by line. Input data is separated by `'\n'`. data is typed by user. like 'input()' .

#### My Question:

1. Is `.read()` or `.readline()` not necessary?
2. I wonder why `for` loop works on `sys.stdin` and how it reads data line by line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation for `sys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin), you'll see that `sys.stdin` (and `sys.stdout` / `sys.stderr`) are just file objects.

> These streams are regular text files like those returned by the `open()` function.

[The documentation about `open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) says:

> The type of file object returned by the `open()` function depends on the mode. When `open()` is used to open a file in a text mode ('w', 'r', 'wt', 'rt', etc.), it returns a subclass of `io.TextIOBase` (specifically `io.TextIOWrapper`).

`TextIOWrapper` inherits from `IOBase`, which has an `__iter__` method. This `__iter__` method allows looping over lines in the file. I can't find where this is noted in the Python documentation, but it is given [in the source code for IOBase](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_io/iobase.c#L58-L60).

> IOBase (and its subclasses) support the iterator protocol, meaning that an IOBase object can be iterated over yielding the lines in a stream.